# Laravel Query Builder - Set Column to NULL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm trying to update my column as `NULL` but the value is passed as a string, and set the column to `0` instead of null.

```
$update = DB::table('users')->where('id', $primary_key)->update(array($column_name => $new_value));
```

How can I ensue that the column is change to `NULL`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `passed as a string`? If you provide `null` value to the query and field is nullable, it will be surely set to `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
$update = DB::table('users')->where('id', $primary_key)->update(
  array
  (
     $column_name => Input::has('FormFieldName') ? Input::get('FormFieldName') : null,
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your mysql table and ensure that the column is nullable and defaults to null.

This can be done in your [migration files](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations):

```
$table->string('awesome_column')->nullable()->default(null);
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to update a column in order to set it to ´null´, how do you do that?